# In Atom, module not defined using promise and functions

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, atom-editor

I'm writing a package for Atom editor using Coffeescript.

My sample code:

```js
module.exports =
class DeclarationTree

  createIndexModules: (files, length) =>
    @modules = new Map()
    ...
  
  onClic = (text) =>
    # PROBLEM **@modules** IS UNDEFINED
    file_array = @modules.get(text)
    console.log file_array
    console.log file_array[0], file_array[1]

  getProvider: ->
    providerName: 'hyperclick-provider',
    # getSuggestionForWord gives me a promise
    getSuggestionForWord: (editor, text, range) ->
      range: range, callback: ->
          onClic(text)
```

Of course, @modules is defined before calling onClic().

I don't know how to solve it, I'm pretty new in Javascript.

Looks like `onClic` with `= ()` defines a non class's method and cannot access to the `@module` (`this.module`)

How to access to a variable I created in a class' method inside a callback function in a promise ?

Thank you !

**Edit: Using a colon:** Thanks for the -1 ;)

```js
module.exports =
class DeclarationTree

  createIndexModules: (files, length) =>
    @modules = new Map()
    console.log this.constructor.name # DeclarationTree
    ...
  
  onClic: (text) =>
    # PROBLEM **@modules** IS UNDEFINED
    file_array = @modules.get(text)
    console.log file_array
    console.log file_array[0], file_array[1]

  getProvider: ->
    providerName: 'hyperclick-provider',
    # getSuggestionForWord gives me a promise
    getSuggestionForWord: (editor, text, range) ->
      range: range, callback: ->
          console.log this.constructor.name # Object
          @onClic(text)
```

Get an `Uncaught TypeError: this.onClic is not a function` error.

Obviously, I cannot access to anything related to `this` object in the `callback` function.

Answer (score 0):

This may be as simple as using a colon after `onClic` instead of an equals sign. Is that what you meant to do?

Right now coffeescript is just writing a function expression in that class declaration scope, so that's why it doesn't have access to `@` / `this`.

EDIT

You're trying to use `this` out of context. You need to bind the function to the scope you want to reference. In coffeescript you can do this easily with a fat arrow function.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried before but I get an error, I think I cannot access to anything related to the object. (I edited my question)